# How do I get provider name to open Ole DB connection?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, connection, provider

So I have a client program and a database on sql server that's on my pc (localdb). I'm trying to set connection on, but it seems like provider is wrong. My connection string looks like this:

```
connection.ConnectionString =
        "Data Source=(localdb)\\Projects;" +
        "Provider=MSIDXS;" +
        "Initial Catalog=TermPaperWork;" +
        "User id=DAZZBOURGH\\Dazzbourgh;" +
        "Integrated Security=True;" +
        "Password=;";
```

So everything is OK there, except provider. I don't get what it is and how to use it and how to know which provider suits my database.

How do I find out my provider for exact base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use http://www.connectionstrings.com when I have questions on the format of a connection string.

Comment: Thx, it did help. Now I'm getting other errors, but my was solved.